# ¿Es posible hacer redirecciones basadas en patrones mediante .htaccess?

Tags: regex, .htaccess

Yo tengo varios miles de URLs en un sitio web en el cual ha cambiado la estructura de los enlaces al migrar el proyecto de Wordpress a Symfony.

Actualmente tengo URLs como estas:

- `homilias-ciclo-a_semana-03_tiempo-cuaresma_dia-01-domingo`
- `homilias_semana-13_tiempo-ordinario_dia-06-viernes_impar`
- `homilias_semana-02_tiempo-cuaresma_dia-03-martes`
- `mc-09_02-10`
- `mt-16_13-19`
- `gal-05_05-20`
- `1cor-01_01-13`

Y quiero saber si hay alguna forma de indicar las redirecciones siguiendo un patrón. Explico cada caso.

Para las URLs del tipo:

```
homilias-ciclo-a_semana-03_tiempo-cuaresma_dia-01-domingo
```

Habría que capturar:

1. La palabra `homilias`,
2. El carácter único que aparece después de `ciclo-`, en este ejemplo es `a`, pero también puede ser `b` o `c`
3. El valor numérico de dos dígitos que aparece después de `semana-`
4. La palabra que aparece después de `tiempo-`
5. La palabra que aparece al final, que en este caso es `domingo`.

Con esos 5 valores capturados se construiría la URL así: `homilias/cuaresma/01/domingo/a`, como se puede observar, el valor capturado en (2) pasará al final de la URL.

Para las URLs del tipo:

```
homilias_semana-13_tiempo-ordinario_dia-06-viernes_impar
```

Habría que capturar:

1. La palabra `homilias`,
2. El valor numérico de dos dígitos que aparece después de `semana-`
3. La palabra que aparece después de `tiempo-`
4. La penúltima palabra que aparece (que sería el día de la semana), en este caso `viernes`
5. La última palabra de la cadena, que en este caso es `impar`.

Con esos datos capturados se construiría esta URL: `homilias/ordinario/13/viernes/impar`

En cuanto a las URLs del tipo:

```
homilias_semana-02_tiempo-cuaresma_dia-03-martes
```

suponen un caso especial, la mismas deberán agregar la palabra `unico` al final de la URL. No sé si esto se pueda expresar en REGEX de algún modo. La cuestión es que en las dos estructuras anteriores, valor del ciclo venía dado por `ciclo-a` en el primer caso, o al final de la URL en el segundo caso: `impar`. Pero aquí no viene indicado y quiero agregar para estos casos la palabra `unico` como ciclo.

Entonces aquí habría que capturar:

1. La palabra `homilias`,
2. El valor numérico de dos dígitos que aparece después de `semana-`
3. La palabra que aparece después de `tiempo-`
4. La penúltima palabra que aparece (que sería el día de la semana), en este caso `martes`
5. Determinar de algún modo, que se trata de un ciclo `unico`.

El resultado final debería ser: `homilias/adviento/02/martes/unico`

Para las otras URLs sería necesario:

1. Determinar si se trata de `evangelios` o de `epistolas`, etc. Por ejemplo, si el contenido de la primera palabra antes del primer `-` es `mt`, `mc`, `lc` o `jn` estamos en un caso de `evangelios`, si es `gal`, `1cor` ... etc, estamos en un caso de `epistolas`
2. Capturar el valor numérico después del primer `-`
3. Capturar la cadena después de `_`.

Las URLs finales de los ejemplos deberían quedar así:

- `homilias`
- `homilias/cuaresma/01/domingo/a`
- `homilias/ordinario/13/viernes/impar`
- `homilias/adviento/02/martes/unico`
- `comentarios/evangelios/mc/09/02-10`
- `comentarios/evangelios/mt/16/13-19`
- `comentarios/epistolas/gal/05/05-20`
- `comentarios/epistolas/1cor/01/01-13`

¿Hay alguna de hacer estos patrones de redirección?

Actualmente lo tengo a mano, pero no es viable, porque son  miles de URLs:

```
Redirect 301 /homilias_semana-13_tiempo-ordinario_dia-06-viernes_impar/ /homilias/cuaresma/01/domingo/a
Redirect 301 /mc-09_02-10/ /comentarios/evangelios/mc/09/02-10/
```

Comment: @Marcos he editado la pregunta, explicando con mayor detalle de dónde saldría cada cosa.

Comment: Vos sabes que me parece que hay ciertas "inconcistencias" en tu actualización. En un caso tomas el número del dia y en los otros 2 el de la semana. En el 3er caso aparece `adviento` pero no explicas porque. Confirmame si las "reescrituras" resultantes que indicas son correctas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si me guio por la descripción enunciada para cada caso (*y no en los resultados*) y teniendo [`mod_alias`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) activado podrías hacerlo así:

```
# Caso "ciclo-x"
RedirectMatch 301 ^/homilias-ciclo-([abc])_semana-([0-9]{2})_tiempo-([a-z]+)_dia-[0-9]{2}-([a-z]+)$ /homilias/$3/$2/$4/$1 

# Caso "sufijo _x"
RedirectMatch 301 ^/homilias_semana-([0-9]{2})_tiempo-([a-z]+)_dia-[0-9]{2}-([a-z]+)_([a-z]+)$ /homilias/$2/$1/$3/$4 

# Caso "unico"
RedirectMatch 301 ^/homilias_semana-([0-9]{2})_tiempo-([a-z]+)_dia-[0-9]{2}-([a-z]+)$ /homilias/$2/$1/$3/unico 

# Caso "comentarios/evangelios"
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(mt|mc|lc|jn)-([0-9]{2})_([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})$ /comentarios/evangelios/$1/$2/$3-$4

# Caso "comentarios/epistolas"
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(gal|1cor)-([0-9]{2})_([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})$ /comentarios/epistolas/$1/$2/$3-$4
```